# displayName not updating in firebase authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase. I am struggling with updating displayName just after registration.
i am using web modular api.

```
const register = () => {
        if (!firstName || !lastName) {
            return alert("Enter Full Name");
        }
        else {
            setName(firstName + ' ' + lastName);
        }
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           .then((result) => {

                console.log("Before UPDATE" + JSON.stringify(result.user))
                updateProfile(result.user,{
                    displayName:name,
                })
            })
            .then(console.log('auth Current USER' + JSON.stringify(auth.currentUser)))
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error)
                console.log(error)
            })
            console.log("AFTER EVRYTHING"+JSON.stringify(auth.currentUser));

    }
```

i followed firebase documentation still i am stuck with this from 2 days. Thanks in Advance.

is there any way i can set displayName during authorization?(WEB APP)

Comment: You need to return updateProfile as it returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `updateProfile()`:

```
return updateProfile(result.user, {
    displayName: name
});
```